# Directx vertex rendering: unable to get texture to display correctly for trapetzoids

Tags: directx, textures, vertex

I'm trying to create 3d effect using vertex and index buffers in 2d (z-coord is 0) using DirectX7.

It's easier to explain with a picture:

[image: Problem's illustration]

The problem is that the lines are broken. They should be straight. To render this image it gets break up in triangles and rendered using DrawIndexedPrimitiveVB. Obviously each of the triangle is skewed a little differently and I don't see why.

Am I missing something trivial here?

I'm not sure if this will help, but the source and destination quads are as follow:

```
    SPoint4:= pBounds4(1, 1, W - 2, H - 2);
    DPoint4:= Point4(ProjTo2dX(i, FlyDist + DeepDist, W), ProjTo2dY(0, FlyDist + DeepDist, H), ProjTo2dX(W - i, FlyDist, W), ProjTo2dY(0, FlyDist, H), ProjTo2dX(W - i, FlyDist, W), ProjTo2dY(H, FlyDist, H), ProjTo2dX(i, FlyDist + DeepDist, W), ProjTo2dY(H, FlyDist + DeepDist, H));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution or at least a workaround. Instead of breaking the image up in 2 triangles, I break it up in many (several horizontal strips, each consisting of 2 triangles). In this case the image looks ok.

[image: less broken lines]

in this case the image is split in 10 strips (20 triangles).

I'll be happy for any comments or other solutions. Thank you.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since I had to use this technique, in order to avoid 3d stuff, so that my application can fall back from DirectX to GDI if necessary.

Comment: actually, this doesn't solve the problem - you now have the same problem multiple times across the geometry - its just less noticeable because the error is proportional to the area of the triangles in the subdivided mesh. you are right that this makes it easier to do with GDI though - although its nothing to do with 2d and everything to do with per-pixel operations.

Comment: Formally you are completely correct but in practice it's good enough and the defect is not noticable. At the time it was my only solution and although I as a developer know it's hacky, the end user doesn't and enjoys the result. I'll try to implement Natan's solution next time I open the project.

Answer (score 3):

One way to map a square/rectangular texture to an arbitrary quad is projective interpolation.  I've written [an article](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/) showing how to do this (using vertex/pixel shaders).

The short version: you interpolate UVs across the quad in a way analogous to how GPUs do it for perspective-correct rendering (which, as you may have noticed, does *not* produce a visible seam between the two triangles).  To do this, you need to calculate a false "depth" value for each vertex of the quad, and do the interpolation using homogeneous coordinates based on this "depth".  Full details are in the article linked above.

Comment: Thanks, this might improve my solution, but I will need to read later when my brain works better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some perspective information to have a proper texture coordinates interpolation on a trapezoid, see

[Problems with texture deformation in OpenGL ES 1.1 on quad made out of triangle strips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748900/problems-with-texture-deformation-in-opengl-es-1-1-on-quad-made-out-of-triangle-s/4764384#4764384)